# Progress Bar or Div over image

Tags: html, css, loading

I would like to simulate a loading effect, so the opacity of the image is changing gradually.

```css
body {
    background-color: #aaa;
    padding: 10px;
}

#progressbar {
    width: 269px;
    height: 269px;
    background-color: #eee;
    clear: both;
}

#progress {
    background: #fff; /*-- Color of the bar --*/
    height: 269px; 
    width: 0%;
    max-width: 269px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
    -moz-animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
    -ms-animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
    animation: progress 2s 1 forwards;
}

#pbaranim {
    height: 269px;
    width: 269px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url("http://i57.tinypic.com/acyid2.jpg");
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5; 
    opacity: 0.5;
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=55);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=55);
    filter: alpha(opacity=55);
}

@-webkit-keyframes progress { 
    from { }

    to { width: 100% }
}

@-moz-keyframes progress { 
    from { }

    to { width: 100% }
}

@-ms-keyframes progress { 
    from { }

    to { width: 100% }
}

@keyframes progress { 
    from { }

    to { width: 100% }
}
```

```html
<div id="progressbar"><div id="progress" ><div id="pbaranim"></div></div></div>
```

In my example, the Div is over the image.
I need the image opacity to become clearer, so the inverse of what I have
Image should appear from 0 to 100%

Makes sense?

thanks for any help

Comment: Do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/qgf2e0gw/

Comment: Not really sorry, the loading effect needs to come from left to right and cover the image once completed. Like this http://oi59.tinypic.com/seswtx.jpg

Comment: Ok, is this what you meant? http://jsfiddle.net/qgf2e0gw/2/

Comment: @DanielLisik yes nearly there, how do I slow down the animation keep the image at the end?

Comment: You'll have to fiddle with `cubic-bezier` to achieve that. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/qgf2e0gw/3/ You can change the specific values interactively on http://cubic-bezier.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the effect with the following code:

**CSS**

```
#progressBar {
    position:relative;
}
#progressImg {
    width:391px;
}
#opacObj {
    -webkit-animation:opacAnimation 4s 1 cubic-bezier(0, 1.09, .66, .96);
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation:opacAnimation 4s 1 cubic-bezier(0, 1.09, .66, .96);
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation:opacAnimation 4s 1 cubic-bezier(0, 1.09, .66, .96);
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation:opacAnimation 4s 1 cubic-bezier(0, 1.09, .66, .96);
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    width:391px;
    height:364px;
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
@-webkit-keyframes opacAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity:0.8;
        left:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0.0;
        left:391px;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes opacAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity:0.8;
        left:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0.0;
        left:391px;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes opacAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity:0.8;
        left:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0.0;
        left:391px;
    }
}
@keyframes opacAnimation {
    0% {
        opacity:0.8;
        left:0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity:0.0;
        left:391px;
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="progressbar">
    <img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/acyid2.jpg" border="0" id="progressImg">
    <div id="opacObj"></div>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qgf2e0gw/5/)**

Comment: 99.9% there @daniellisik, I ve updated the fiddle with different values, http://jsfiddle.net/qgf2e0gw/6/.  Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Change the nesting hierarchy of your objects, namedly progress and pbaranim divs, as this

```
<div id="progressbar"><div id="pbaranim"><div id="progress" ></div></div></div>
```

You will progress from there on, by adding another image with the from color, and keep current image as the to color (from and to colors of animation) etc...

Comment: see what I mean here, https://jsfiddle.net/fmbseg26/1/, than you can take it from there, hope it helps

Comment: I tried your code, but again, I want the image with dots to become 100% so really blue. Image starts at 20% opacity, the progress starts and covers image which slowly become 100% opaque following the progress of the div?

Comment: try displaying the same image in there again ;) keep using css background-image feature so that the browser loads it once and caches it, so in a gist have another div like pbaranim which stays while the other one gets covered

Comment: sorry you lost me there

Comment: You slow it down at progress css, at animation rules https://jsfiddle.net/fmbseg26/3/

Comment: the speed is right but the image should become clearer like in DanielLisik example  jsfiddle.net/qgf2e0gw/2